# Rewrite \url{https://example.com/path} to \href{https://example.com/path}{path} from macro

Tags: hyperref, urls, text-manipulation

This document is cut down from a BibTeX-generated .bbl file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\showDOI}[1]{\textsc{doi:}#1}
\begin{document}
\urldef\tempurl\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}
\showDOI{\tempurl}
\end{document}
```

It renders like this:

[image]

I want to get output as if the document had read

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\showDOI}[1]{\textsc{doi:}#1}
\begin{document}
\showDOI{\href{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}%
              {\UrlFont 10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}
\end{document}
```

i.e.

[image]

with the PDF hyperlink still pointing to the full URL.

But, because I don't want to have to mess with the .bst file, and because I need the `\verb`-like behavior of `\url` applied before `\showDOI` is expanded — some of the DOIs in my actual bibliography have underscores and/or percent signs in them — I want to accomplish this by changing **only** the definition of `\showDOI`, not the way it is used.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Which bib style are you using? Some have options to automatically display the doi like this.

Comment: @samcarter "ACM-Reference-Format.bst" (see http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) which is, quite frankly, terrible, although not the worst journal template I've ever had to work with (it's going to be hard to beat the one that thought it was a good idea to redefine `\p@`!)  It does not have any convenient knobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plain text of an url created by `\urldef` can be modified by defining `\UrlLeft` and `\UrlRight`. Adapted from the [`url` package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf), using `xstring` for string processing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}   % for presentation only

\newcommand{\showDOI}[1]{%
\let\oldleft\UrlLeft%
\let\oldright\UrlRight%
\def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\StrGobbleLeft{##1}{16}}%
\textsc{doi:} #1%
\let\UrlLeft\oldleft%
\let\UrlRight\oldright%
}

\begin{document}
\url{http://www.regular-url.com/}

\urldef\tempurl\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}
\showDOI{\tempurl}

\url{http://www.other-url.com/}
\end{document}
```

This works because `hyperref` creates the link first with the original argument and then formats the link using the `url` package, which in turn uses the provided definition. Note that the definitions need to be saved and restored around the DOI display to avoid truncating of normal urls.

Result (link target is shown as tooltip):

[image]

Comment: This works nicely, but just to make sure I understand, `\StrGobbleLeft{##1}{16}` is chopping the first 16 characters off the URL, which is exactly how long `https://doi.org/` happens to be?

Comment: @zwol that's correct :) In case you want to make it a bit more flexible (for example also allowing for `http://doi.org`) you could look into the substring matching functions provided by `xstring` (or `stringstrings`, or `coolstr`), there are several commands that can be useful for this.

Comment: or incorporate @Herbert 's approach with `#1//#2/#3`, of course.

Comment: I am going with this answer but with `\def\UrlLeft##1//##2/##3\UrlRight{##3}` as in Herbert's answer -- as well as not hardwiring the length of `https://doi.org/` this has the advantage of not requiring any additional packages.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\showDOI#1{\expandafter\showDOI@i#1\@nil}
\def\showDOI@i#1//#2/#3\@nil{\textsc{DOI:} \href{#1//#2/#3}{\UrlFont#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\tempurl{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}
\showDOI{\tempurl}%

\showDOI{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this seems to result in an error if `\showDOI{\tempurl}` (after `\urldef`) from the OP is used, possibly because of the internals of `\urldef`?

Comment: see edited answer. When using `\urldef` it is not so easy to handle.

Comment: `Runaway argument?
\protect \tempurl  \@nil  
! Paragraph ended before \showDOI@i was complete.`  No, use of `\urldef` is not optional, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Let's remove anything coming before `doi.org/` (so even if you happen to have `http` instead of `https`, the macro will work the same).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showDOI}{m}
 {
  \textsc{doi:}
  %\nobreakspace % if you want a space, uncomment this
  \zwol_showdoi:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__zwol_showdoi_tl
\tl_new:N \l__zwol_showdoi_full_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zwol_showdoi:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   { % single token
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { \cs_to_str:N #1 ~ }
     {% we assume it is \urldef
      \__zwol_showdoi_urldef:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 ~ }
     }
     {
      \tl_set:Nx \l__zwol_showdoi_tl { #1 }
     }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__zwol_showdoi_tl { #1 }
   }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l__zwol_showdoi_full_tl \l__zwol_showdoi_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A .*doi\.org/ } { } \l__zwol_showdoi_tl
  \href{\l__zwol_showdoi_full_tl}{\UrlFont\l__zwol_showdoi_tl}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zwol_showdoi_urldef:N
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l__zwol_showdoi_tl #1
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{url} \cB. (.*) \cE. } { \1 } \l__zwol_showdoi_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__zwol_showdoi_urldef:N { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\urldef\tempurl\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}

\showDOI{\tempurl}

\showDOI{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comnet.2004.08.013}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may need to update your TeX distribution, because regexes entered the expl3 kernel quite recently. If you can't update, add `\usepackage{l3regex}`.

Comment: Like Herbert's answer, this does not work when `\tempurl` is defined with `\urldef` as shown in the original code sample.  Use of `\urldef` is one of the things I cannot change.

Comment: @zwol Now it accepts also macros defined with `\urldef`.